# lmer gives error: `assignment of an object of class "numeric" is not valid for @'Dim' in an object of class "dgTMatrix"`

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

While fitting a mixed effects model with `lme4::lmer`, I encountered the following error:

> Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :    assignment of an
>   object of class "numeric" is not valid for @'Dim' in an object of
>   class "dgTMatrix"; is(value, "integer") is not TRUE

I performed a google search but could find no result which contains this whole error message. I finally worked out the cause by reverting my code to a state where it worked. I have provided an answer below with the resolution.

As from the error message the cause is hard to infer but the error can happen easily, I document the cause of the error here as future reference.

The error occurred in the following code:

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (0 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

Comment: Please add more information. Include a code snippet and what you have already tried.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg my code is sufficient to reproduce the error from scratch and to see it goes away using my answer to this question. (sleepstudy is an example dataset of the lme4 package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the source of the error was just a typo which resulted from prior fiddling around with the model.

To include a "simple" random variable (which directly influences the dependent variable and not one of the other fixed effects), one must write `(1 | U)` where `U` is the column in the data set holding the realizations of the random variable. It is *not* `(0 | U)` like accidentially written in the question.

So the example code of the question must be:

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```